# VirtualMin + Wordpress Multiple Domain, same site, same ip

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cloudflare, lets-encrypt, virtualmin

I'm running a website and for a couple months I'll have to disable my primary domain. Right now I'm running this website in CentOS 7.3 Webmin 1.840 and with Let's Encrypt Certificate.

I need to make this website available to other domain in real-time, and at the same time, disable my primary one. Something like this:

primarydomain.com (disabled for a while, but providing real-time data to secondary domain)
secondarydomain.tk (all data from primarydomain.com being shown here, just like proxy/domain alias, with all redirects, links, images... set to secondarydomain.tk).

I've already setup Cloudflare for the secondarydomain.tk only with A type (IP) and as soon as I type secondarydomain.tk in the web browser, it get's redirected to primarydomain.com.

I've tried to create virtual server in all modes in Virtualmin: Top-level server, Sub-server and Alias of primarydomain.com (with/without own email), but the maximum I could achieve was when I browse secondarydomain.tk, it shows primarydomain.com homepage, but ALL LINKS it's still linked to primarydomain.com. So I can't click anywhere.

Besides that, all traffic should be in SSL (https), so my htaccess of primary domain is set to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.primarydomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

By the way, the secondarydomain CAN (and probably SHOULD) share the same vhost folder, so:

> /home/primarydomain

Should be equal for both.

Could someone help me achieve this?
Btw, my english is rusty and probably I've made lots of english mistakes above :P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because that WordPress is database driven. So, even if you create a virtual server in Virtualmin with new domain name, WordPress is going to use the old domain stored in the database.

To achieve this, you'll need to change all the links in the WordPress database to the new domain name.

**Backup your database before you proceed**

You could use [this](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) tool to change all the links to the new domain. Replace the old domain name with the new domain name.

Comment: Well.... if it's needed to edit database links, it's better to also change primary domain in VirtualMin panel =P.

Comment: Hey buddy! This tool worked great! Everything is running smoothly =) THANKS!

Comment: Yeah you must have an entry for the new domain as a primary domain and map it to the WordPress directory.